# Jquery populate dropdownbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

Im trying to populate a dropdown list using jquery. The population has but the default text "Select Model" is replaced by the new data..

Javascript:

```
 data = $.map(data, function (item, a) {
    return"<option value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text    + "</option>";
    $("#SelectedModel").html(data.join(""));
```

HTML:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedModel,Model.models,"Select Model")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use append:

```
//to reset select options
$('#SelectedModel option').not(':eq(0)').remove();
//then append data    
$("#SelectedModel").append(data.join(""));
```

Or with .html(), should be:

```
$("#SelectedModel").html($("#SelectedModel").html()+data.join(""));
```

Comment: This appends the data from previous ajax call. I want to replace all the options but keep the dropdown label"Select Model"

Comment: Dude you rock socks. Thanks a lot buddy it works. I spent hours trying to make this work.